# h2o.ai AutoML StackedEnsemble giving falsely superior validation metrics

Tags: h2o

I believe I've uncovered a bug (or limitation) in the h2o.ai AutoML StackedEnsemble validation metrics.

When running AutoML with only one model type (in this case XGBoost) and n-fold cross validation, I was surprised to see that the BestOfFamily StackedEnsemble scored better than any of the individual XGBoost models. Which should not be possible, since the BestOfFamily StackedEnsemble in this scenario contains only one model, the leading XGBoost model, and therefore should have identical validation metrics to it. I confirmed by checking the StackedEnsemble did indeed only contain the best XGBoost model, yet had different and superior validation metrics.

My best hypothesis for this is that the metalearner algorithm (at least the default GLM one) does not take into account the weights I had assigned to the training data. Some of the observations in the training data are related, and I needed to reduce their weight relative to more unique observations (if that doesn't make sense or is wrong, feel free to correct as I'm fairly amateur, but it's beside the point). When I discovered this anomaly, I was only using XGBoost, but I do use AutoML with multiple model categories and am concerned the problem will affect those Stacked Ensembles and their rankings as well.

So unfortunately, unless this can be explained or corrected, I will not be able to use Stacked Ensembles in my current endeavors, since I can't trust the validation metrics. Does anyone have such an explanation or method of fixing the problem?

h2o Version: 3.28.0.1

Used in conjunction with R Version: 3.6.1

As requested, below is some quickly cobbled together R code to generate some synthetic data and apply AutoML that should reproduce the problem.

Further edit: When I make all the weights the same in this example, the validation metric for the Best of Family Stacked Ensemble are closer to, but still not identical to, the single XGBoost model is contains. I don't understand how this can be true, as a Stacked Ensemble of one model should be have outputs identical to that one model, correct?

```
h2o.init()

DF<-data.frame(c(rep(T,1000), rep(F,1000)))
colnames(DF)<-"RESULT"

DF$WEIGHT<-rep(c(rep(1,500), rep(2,500)), 2)

DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_1"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 1, sd = 1)
DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_1"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 1, sd = 2)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_1"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 2, sd = 1)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_1"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 2, sd = 2)

DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_2"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 1, sd = 1)
DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_2"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 1, sd = 2)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_2"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 2, sd = 1)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_2"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 2, sd = 2)

DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_3"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 1, sd = 1)
DF[which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_3"]<-rnorm(length(which(DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 1, sd = 2)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1), "VAR_3"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==1)), mean = 2, sd = 1)
DF[which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2), "VAR_3"]<-rnorm(length(which(!DF$RESULT & DF$WEIGHT==2)), mean = 2, sd = 2)

TRAIN<-as.h2o(DF, "TRAIN")

AUTOML<-h2o.automl(project_name = "ERROR_TEST",
                   training_frame = "TRAIN",
                   y="RESULT",
                   weights_column = "WEIGHT",
                   stopping_metric = "logloss",
                   modeling_plan = list(list(name="XGBoost", alias='defaults'), "StackedEnsemble"),
                   sort_metric = "logloss",
                   verbosity = "info")

print(AUTOML@leaderboard)
```

Comment: Hi, I am happy to look into this if you can post a reproducible example.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Erin. I can't post my actual data which would be impractical and also contains protected information, but I mocked up a synthetic example that demonstrates the problem (basically). When I run the below code, the h2o AutoMl leaderboard showed the Best of Family Stacked Ensemble had a logos=0.574, AUC=0.771. It contains one of the three XGBoost models trained, which itself had logloss=0.598, AUC=0.742. Your results may differ slightly as the training data has a randomized element. **Having some trouble posting, will update shortly - sorry, new to stack overflow!**

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, the metrics should be identical.  In fact, it doesn't make sense to allow a user to train a Stacked Ensemble with one model anyway.  I have filed two bug reports related to this issue: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7195 and https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7196

Comment: Also, I wanted to mention that the H2O GLM algorithm, which we use as the metalearner, will take weights into account, so it's not related to that.  (the discrepancy between metrics occurs whether there are weights or not)